# How do I separate and parse out data from multiple columns into separate rows (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have columns with multiple values delimited by a comma in each column and row. I am trying to separate them out into separate rows. If i have a null value for one of them (as shown below) I will still include the null value as long as one of the other values are still present for that particular row.

What I'm given

```
First_Name (John,  ,Phil)
Last_Name  (Smith,No, ) 
Location  (CA,GA,NY)
```

What I want

```
(John, Smith, CA)
( , No, GA)
(Phil, ,NY)
```

I've tried using the regexp_substr method but it's not returning any rows that have a null in any one of the 3 columns listed above.

Comment: Show the query which you tried.

Comment: select trim(regexp_substr(first_name,'[^,]+', 1, 1)) first_name,   trim(regexp_substr(last_name,'[^,]+',1, 2)) last,name,                                             trim(regexp_substr(location,'[^,]+', 1, 3)) location                                                                    from table_name                                                                                                     connect by regexp_substr(first_name,'[^,]+', 1, 1 is not null

Comment: So, in the `First_Name` input, what is between the commas? It looks like two spaces. Ideally, if the first name is "missing", there should be **nothing** between the commas, not even *one* space. `'John,,Phil'`. Similarly, in `Last_Name` the second comma should be right at the end of the string (to mark a NULL at the end), there should be no spaces after it. Is that what the strings REALLY look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
  inputs ( id, first_name, last_name, location ) as (
    select 101, 'John,,Phil' , 'Smith,No,'   , 'CA,GA,NY' from dual union all
    select 102, 'Jo,Al,Ed,Li', 'Ng,Tso,,Roth', ',ZZ,,BB'  from dual 
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select id,
       regexp_substr(first_name, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as first_name,
       regexp_substr(last_name , '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as last_name,
       regexp_substr(location  , '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as location
from   inputs
connect by level <= regexp_count(first_name, ',') + 1
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

  ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME    LOCATION
---- ----------- ------------ --------
 101 John        Smith        CA      
 101             No           GA      
 101 Phil                     NY      
 102 Jo          Ng                   
 102 Al          Tso          ZZ      
 102 Ed                               
 102 Li          Roth         BB
```

Comment: would the solution change if we weren't inserting the data but rather selecting them column by column from a 'staging' table?

Comment: @icerabbit -  I don't understand the question. The solution I provided doesn't insert the data. Do you mean the WITH clause? I marked it very clearly to be for testing purposes only; you only need the code from `select id, ...` on, but you must use the name of your staging table and columns from it. Or are you asking how to STORE the RESULT of this query? If so, use an INSERT statement with this SELECT query.

Comment: sorry, i misread and got your solution confused with the other one. if i want to substitute a carriage return instead of the comma, how would i do this? is there a special code for this?

Comment: @icerabbit - The code for carriage return is `chr(13)`. But again, I don't understand. Is the data in single columns of text, but the text itself (while a "single value" from an outside view) is in fact extending over several lines, with one value per line? Be very careful there; if the input comes from Unix/Linux then there are only line feeds (not carriage returns!) - that's `chr(10)`, but if it is coming from Windows it's carriage return AND line feed. What are you using to do the import, though? All of this should be handled as the data is being imported, not after the fact.

Comment: So it seems like the data was given to me already loaded into a table. What is happening is for each unique identifier i have several first_names, last_names and locations all separated by some character that I am not sure of. An example of first_names i can receive in a single column are: CarlosMonta

Comment: To see exactly what you have, use the `DUMP()` function. Google for it, you will see what it is, what it does, and how it is used. Use `dump(col_name)` to see what is in column `col_name`; look specifically for the values 10 and 13 (for line feed and carriage return) if that is what you suspect. If you need more help you should open a new thread, since the question you started with is different (and has been completely answered already).

Comment: thanks! and sorry about that... ill mark your response as the best answer, cant thank you enough for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 

TYPE etype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
erec etype;
BEGIN

 for rec IN  ( SELECT first_name,last_name,location FROM Table1 )
 LOOP

 WITH fname
     AS (SELECT LEVEL   lvl,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.first_name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)First_name
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.first_name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL),
     lname
     AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.last_name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)Last_Name
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.last_name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL),
     loc
     AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.location, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)Location
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.location, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT first_name
       ||','
       || last_name
       ||','
       || location  BULK COLLECT INTO erec 
FROM   fname fn
       FULL OUTER join lname ln
                    ON fn.lvl = ln.lvl
       FULL OUTER join loc lo
                    ON ln.lvl = lo.lvl;  

FOR i IN 1..erec.COUNT
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(erec(i));  
END LOOP;

END LOOP;     

END;
/
```

Comment: when i use this for a larger data set i;m returning multiple first names, last names , etc. that aren't supposed to be correlated to each other (maybe due to the full outer join?)                                                                                       for example i am now returning : (John, Smith, CA) (John, Smith, NY) (John, Smith, LA), etc.

Comment: No, It  works for your original question. you modified the question.

Comment: awesome, so how do i do it for larger data sets?

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and mark  as best answer if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Let's say I add a unique identifier to my design (such as a ID) would that change anything? Would that help performance? You don't have to answer since this is further complicating the original question but thought it wouldnt hurt to ask. Either way you're going to get the 'best answer' i think

Comment: @icerabbit -  There is no reason to use PL/SQL here (much less loops) for something that can be done cleanly in SQL.

Comment: Yes. But at least an upvote from op won't do any harm if not the best answer - for a free solution.

Comment: i can't upvote yet but i can select the best answer for some reason... maybe because im a new member?

Comment: Ok. Do remember me and come back to do it when you can!! ..:)